# Is the Super Saiyan 4 transformation from Dragon Ball GT confirmed non-canon?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

Since the release of Dragon Ball Super, it is confirmed by Akira Toriyama and Toei that Dragon Ball GT is non-canon anymore. But I was wondering if there was still some elements of GT that have maybe been kept by the author and which would still be considered canon in the actual Dragon Ball Super manga/anime, and notably the Super Saiyan 4 transformation achieved by Son Goku and Vegeta.

I do know that the events that led to those transformations are not present in the real series timeline, and so that they would not be able to transform in SSJ4 right now. But did Akira Toriyama **confirmed** the fact of totally ruling out this transformation?

Comment: If you want to see something more of the Super Saiyan 4 transformation after Dragon Ball GT you can read the Dragon Ball Heroes manga which has the same writer/artist as the Dragon Ball Super manga (Toyotaro) . They are making short animation "movies" of 12 minutes or so featuring supposedly "non canon" characters like Broly in Dragon Ball 4d, who fights Goku Super Saiyan Blue, so I guess nobody can completely dismiss the possibility of seeing SSJ4 in a short "non canon" movie or something mixed with "canon" characters

Comment: @Pablo One of the alternate universe Saiyans in Super appears to have a Broly-like transformation. It's not inconceivable they could just throw SSJ4 on someone in much the same fashion, though to date they haven't.

Comment: I'm not talking about Super, what about if they make a Dragon Ball Heroes movie someday? They've made a manga, so it's not impossible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He didn't confirm it, but he didn't create the design either. It was created by a guy named Nakatsuru. Up to today, in Dragon Ball, canon is considered what is based on Akira Toriyama's original ideas. The 80's and 90's movies weren't canon because Akira Toriyama wasn't involved in them. The 80's manga was canon because it was drawn by him. The fillers in the 90's series weren't canon because they weren't based on Akira Toriyama's ideas. So yes, you can say it isn't canon, that doesn't necessarily mean it is completely ruled out, though most likely it is. The final kamehameha was an idea from the video games which wasn't canon, yet it still appeared later in the Dragon Ball super series.